# How to remove extra start item from boot menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, boot

I bought a laptop recently. While Windows 7 was installing, the battery died. So I plugged in the charger and re-installed Windows 7 Home Basic from the start. After completion of the procedure I now have 2 `Windows` folders in my `C:\` drive, so I deleted the old `Windows` folder.

The problem is, while booting time it shows two `Windows 7` options, although I already deleted the old `Windows` folder.

How can I remove old `Windows 7` option from my boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage your boot sequence and order in `msconfig`.

Just run `msconfig.exe`, then go to the `boot` tab and you can delete extra one, note that you can't delete current one:

[image]